# Airflow variables/macros for execution_date

Tags: python-3.6, airflow

I'd like to use some Airflow macros as a variable that I can place at the top of my file instead of in a function.

This is how my code is set up currently. I have 3 tasks in this example which each refer to a function. I wanted to avoid using xcoms, so I place the **kwargs in each function. I also saw that there is a macro to format the execution_date so I would like to replace my two functions with that, if possible.

```
def select_remote_file(execution_date):
    remote_file_date = execution_date.strftime(REMOTE_DATE_FORMAT)
    remote_file_path = REMOTE_PATH + PREFIX + remote_file_date + EXTENSION
    return remote_file_path

def prepare_local_file(execution_date):
    local_file_date = execution_date.strftime(LOCAL_DATE_FORMAT)
    local_file_path = str(LOCAL_PATH / PREFIX) + local_file_date + EXTENSION
    return local_file_path

def extract(**kwargs):
    execution_date = kwargs['execution_date'] - dt.timedelta(days=3)
    local_file_path = prepare_local_file(execution_date=execution_date)
    remote_file_path = select_remote_file(execution_date=execution_date)

def transform(**kwargs):
    execution_date = kwargs['execution_date'] - dt.timedelta(days=3)
    local_file_path = prepare_local_file(execution_date=execution_date)
    remote_file_path = select_remote_file(execution_date=execution_date)

def load(**kwargs):
    execution_date = kwargs['execution_date'] - dt.timedelta(days=3)
    local_file_path = prepare_local_file(execution_date=execution_date)

t1 = PythonOperator(task_id=f'extract_{FILE}',
                         python_callable=download_raw_from_sftp,
                         provide_context=True,
                         dag=dag)
t2 = PythonOperator(task_id=f'convert_utf_{FILE}',
                        python_callable=convert_utf,
                        provide_context=True,
                        dag=dag)

t3 = PythonOperator(task_id=f'compress_{FILE}',
                          python_callable=compress_file,
                          provide_context=True,
                          dag=dag)
```

My goal is to instead have a variable at the top of the file that I can refer to in my functions instead of editing them one by one. Is this possible?

EXECUTION_DATE = {{ ds }}

or for some files

EXECUTION_DATE = ds_add('ds', -3)

Comment: I think the real (and valid) question here is not really about execution date, more like: Does Jinja process anything in the dag definition file other than operator fields marked as templated? I think the answer is no, which is a bit sad as it would be useful in quite a few situations. I have messed with this and asked at length with no solution. Hope there is one eventually.